# How many dimensions are in the electromagnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, degrees-of-freedom

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352251/377431) asks how many dimensions there are in the electric field for the purposes of better understanding polarization. However, the other answers don't seem to fully address the question, and it is a high traffic question so I do not have enough reputation to answer.

The answer is that in a mathematical description of classical electrostatics, the field is 6 dimensional. The first 3 dimensions are spatial and the remaining 3 dimensions are the directional components of the magnitude of the force. The field can be thought of as having a value at each point in space, and that value is a force that acts on electric charges, which is a vector with 3 directional components. In electrodynamics, time is added as a 7th dimension. And in electromagnetism, another 3 dimensions hold the directional force components of the magnetic field. This makes a a total of 10 dimensions.

However, I think this answer lacks nuance especially with respect to the original goal of understanding polarization and I was hoping to answer:

1. can all problems in electromagnetism use a subset of these 10 dimensions to find a solution?
2. are additional dimensions or variables needed to describe how electromagnetism works in materials with phonons/vibrations modes or other interactions with matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's clear up some terminology.

At a mathematical level, you can think of the electric field as a *function* that maps points in spacetime to an electric field vector. Ignoring gravity (so we can assume the spacetime has no curvature), the electric field is a map $R^4 \rightarrow R^3$. What this notation means is that the electric field maps 4 real numbers (space and time) to 3 real numbers (the $x,y,z$ components of the electric field)$^\star$. In other words, the "input space" for the electric field has four dimensions (3 space plus one time), and the output space has three dimensions (3 components of the electric field).

**You generally should not add the dimensions of the input and output spaces of a function.** I have personally never come across a situation where it would be meaningful to add the dimensions of the input and output spaces for a function. Perhaps, there is some weird special case where it does make sense, that someone will bring up in the comments.

Continuing our mathematical description, you can also think of the magnetic field as a map $R^4 \rightarrow R^3$ from a 4 dimensional space to a 3 dimensional space. You can also think of the electromagnetic field as being the combination of the electric and magnetic fields$^\dagger$, so you can think of the electromagnetic field as a map $R^4 \rightarrow R^6$. This is more or less what you said in your question (the electromagnetic field has 6 components at each point in 4 spacetime dimensions) -- but again, **it is not meaningful to add the dimensions of the input and output spaces of a function**.

So much for the electromagnetic field.

If you go one level deeper, you can ask not just about how to represent the electromagnetic field mathematically, but how to actually solve the underlying differential equations (Maxwell's equations) that govern the evolution of the 6 components of the electric and magnetic fields. I will not go through a detailed derivation here, but if you are careful you find that among Maxwell's equations appear four *constraints* -- or equations without time derivatives. These are conditions that any initial data must satisfy in order to be a candidate, realistic electromagnetic field. As a result of these constraints, there are only 2 (=6-4) *physical degrees of freedom* in the electromagnetic field. These correspond to the two polarizations of light; you can think of them as left and right circular polarization, for example.

If you include matter into the picture, then the number of relevant variables increases. How much the number of variables increases depends on the type of matter you are modeling and how accurate you want your model to be. If you want to be "exact", then to represent around a mole of ordinary matter you should include something like $10^{24}$ new variables corresponding to the positions and momenta of all the electrons, protons, and neutrons that make up your matter. In reality, you will probably make some choices to model your matter as some kind of dielectric or conductor. Then the devil is in the details for exactly how you create this model. For example, a perfect conductor can be modeled without parameters, by imposing appropriate boundary conditions at the surface of the conductor. Meanwhile, often for dielectrics, people will introduce the *polarization field* $\vec{P}$ (another map from space and time to 3 components of a vector) and assume some relationship between the polarization field and the electric field (or its cousin the displacement field).

---

$^\star$ As an aside, to be technically correct the map is actually $R^{3,1} \rightarrow R^3$, where $R^{3,1}$ denotes Minkowski spacetime with 3 spatial and 1 time dimension, but that's a relatively unimportant detail for this question

$^\dagger$ In more sophisticated (or at least relativistic) treatments, you can think of these field components as being the 6 components of an antisymmetric tensor called the *field strength tensor*, but exactly what you call these six numbers is just semantics.

Comment: I have some questions about your "6 variables minus 4 constraints is 2 polarizations of light." If you aren't in free space does this change? If you consider charge and current density to be totally free parameters are there more degrees of freedom? Also, I'm questioning if we really want to arrive at "4 spacetime dimensions mapped into 2 degrees of freedom after constraints". Because for each $\vec{k}$ (angular wavenumber) we have two amplitudes _and two phases_, so I would think we should have 3 dimensions mapping to 4 when we describe light in free space.

Comment: @AXensen Starting with the second part of your question... You can count degrees of freedom in different ways. What I mean is that you can write Maxwell's equations as 2 second order differential equations, plus 4 constraints on the initial data. 2 second order differential equations encode 2 amplitudes and 2 phases. Eg, the solution to the one second order equation $\ddot{x}=-\omega^2 x$ has an amplitude and a phase. You can also formulate them as 4 first order differential equations (the Hamiltonian point of view), and then you get a more explicit map from equation to amplitude and phase.

Comment: @AXensen For the first part of your question... Yes, if you add $N$ matter particles, then there will be $N$ degrees of freedom for matter, plus $2$ degrees of freedom for light.

Comment: If you could concoct a medium where, say, left polarized light did not propagate, then that would change the effective number of degrees of freedom for the electromagnetic field in the medium to be 1 instead of 2. Off hand I am not sure if that's possible, although I don't immediately see a reason you couldn't do that in a sufficiently weird system. Also, sometimes you can get "pseudoparticles" that arise from interactions from the electromagnetic field and a lattice, see [polaritons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polariton).

Comment: thanks for going into more depth on that for me

Comment: "I have personally never come across a situation where it would be meaningful to add the dimensions of the input and output spaces for a function."  Try Googling "total space of bundle".

Comment: What I am trying to get at is the total representation of the "state", which captures all relevant information. But I agree that spacetime is independent. And to @AXensen 's question, if we know Ex and Ey, don't we also need to know the charge density to obtain Ez? An equation might capture the relationship, but we cannot know the force value without additional information, right?

Comment: @SvenVoigt "All the relevant information" -- what do you mean by this? Here are two possible interpretations. (a) You want to go and measure the electric and magnetic fields on a lattice of $N$ spacetime points (without using any knowledge of Maxwell's equations), how many measurements do I need to make? Then the answer is $6N.$ (b) You want to calculate what the fields and charges/currents will do at some later time given knowledge of them at some initial time. If the charges and currents are *known* functions of spacetime, then you need to solve for $2$ independent components of the field.

Comment: If the charges/currents are not known, but associated with some other dynamical degrees of freedom (such as electric dipoles in a dielectric), then you need to specify how you are going to model these components. Say it takes $M$ degrees of freedom to model the charges and currents. Then in general you're going to need to solve $2+M$ equations of motion (plus, you need to make sure that your initial data is consistent with the constraints implied by Maxwell's equations).

Comment: Two common cases are perfect conductors and dielectrics. For a perfect conductor, you don't actually introduce any new matter degrees of freedom at all, you just impose appropriate boundary conditions on the surface of the conductor. A common way to model electromagnetic fields in dieletrics is to introduce new fields for the *bound charge density* and *bound current*, as well as *free charge density* and *free current* (which are assumed known), as well as the *displacement* and *magnetizing* fields. Then you assume some phenomenological relationship between the electric and magnetic fields..

Comment: ... and the displacement and magnetizing fields (in the simplest case a linear relationship). Then you solve [Maxwell's equations in matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Macroscopic_formulation), plus the phenomenological "constituent relationships", to get the electric and magnetic fields. If you break down this model, the free charges/currents are assumed known, while the bound charges/currents take the values that are needed to satisfy various boundary conditions, so at the end of the day there are still 2 degrees of freedom in this model.

Comment: What's basically going on in those models for matter is that one assumes that the charges/currents are either (a) controlled by the experimenter, or (b) determined by the behavior of the fields. This is good enough in a lot of applications, but obviously isn't totally realistic. In reality there is also thermal motion of the charge carriers, for example. So as always in physics, there is a tradeoff between wanting a complex model that captures reality, vs a simple model that can be solved and tell you something useful. All this to say, there is not a unique way to handle matter.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for writing that up! Yes, I was more in line with the state measuring N spacetime points. And the reason is that while you may know some controlled charges/currents by the experimenter, there are of course unknowns such as some background EM field error that could be modeled as some error at the boundaries for example. And yeah it is an interesting point that materials modeling uses additional fields to represent EM interactions, although the EM field is the more fundamental information. Makes you wonder if there is something even more fundamental than the force on a charge.

Answer (score 0):

"The answer is that in a mathematical description of classical electrostatics, the field is 6 dimensional."

This very much risks confusing people because:

- Fields don't have dimensions.
- What you presumably meant to say is that the field **takes its values** in a six-dimensional space.

Better yet, the field is a section of a rank-3 vector bundle over a 3-dimensional space (or some variant of this, as in the remainder of your answer).

Worded like that, the OP might not have the background to understand this answer --- so a good answer would find a rewording that explains the necessary concepts.  But that good answer should still be accurate.